# Android - Run UI-dependant code right after main layout has finished displaying

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am writing my first Android application. I have an `ExpandableListView` on my main layout which takes some time to load (~5s). I need to call a static method before or after the UI has been displayed in theory, but that method absolutely needs to be able to display an `AlertDialog`. From my tests, the UI needs to be displayed before any AlertDialog can be shown, which makes sense.

From my understanding, the application displays the UI when `onResume()` returns. However, there doesn't seem to be any easy way to execute code on the UI thread right after `onResume()` returns so that I can display an `AlertDialog` other than using `onPostExecute()` from `AsyncTask`, which needs to return before it displays any graphic dialog/Toast from my tests, which I can't have.

I have spent many hours trying things like `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, `Runnable` and `AsyncTask`, but I realize now that none of these can work for various reasons and I'm out of ideas.

**Edit: code**

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    MessageQueue.IdleHandler h = new MessageQueue.IdleHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean queueIdle()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
            dlgAlert.setMessage("This is an alert with no consequence");
            dlgAlert.setTitle("App Title");
            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
            dlgAlert.create().show();
            return true;
        }
    };
    this.getMainLooper().myQueue().addIdleHandler(h);
}
```

Comment: 5s to load view... I hope you are not doing this on UI Thread.
You can try to call runOnUIThread method right before onResume returns.

Comment: tried to use a `Handler` in `onResume` ?

Comment: @KamenStoykov thanks for your response; I tried `runOnUIThread` right before `onResume()` returns, but the UI still isn't being displayed at the time my method fires. I will try `Handler` later when I get the chance.

Comment: so use `MessageQueue#addIdleHandler` and show your dialog in `IdleHandler`

Comment: @pskink I have my `IdleHandler`, but how should I instanciate or where should I get the MessageQueue for the current activity?

Comment: read `MessageQueue` documentation

Comment: @pskink I found the queue, it looks like my auto-complete had a quirk. I am now suddenly getting I/O error when trying to connect my phone to debug...... ("I/O Error: Connection refused: connect" with device NAME not appearing in the device list). I've restarted the device several times + re-enabled USB-debugging. No luck yet. I will be sure to let you know if it works.

Comment: @pskink I couldn't make it work. I posted the code.

Comment: `queueIdle` is not called?

Comment: it is called twice with an interval of ~1s, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: I've had another idea though: I think I can make this work by calling my static method from a new thread before `OnResume()` returns and using an `AsyncTask` with the main activity's context in my static method to display dialogs, but I don't have time to test it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution; it works but I'm sure it could be made better/more elegant. To reiterate the goal: I need to run code that displays Dialogs *right after* the main layout of the main activity is displayed.

**What this code does:** This code allows you to execute `MyClass.doTask(args)` if the user presses the positive button of an `AlertDialog` right after the main layout has displayed and show a `ProgressDialog` until the task is finished.

In your worker thread, you can also use a `static HashMap<Dialog, Boolean>` or something similar to easily keep track of the states of all embedded Dialogs if you have many, but all your Dialogs must be `static` for this to work.

In your main Activity class:

```
private static boolean staticInitializerFired = false;
private static MyType staticArg = myVal;

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(!staticInitializerFired)
    {
        staticInitializerFired = true;
        final Context ctx = this;
        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                MyClass.staticMethod(ctx, staticArg);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
}
```

In MyClass:

```
private static boolean dlg0Showing = true; //preset initial state so worker thread is notified correctly before the dialog is actually built and shown in the UI thread
private static boolean dlg1Showing = false;
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private static void showDialogAndDoTask(final Context context)
{
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            dlg.setMessage("My message... Yes/No ?");
            dlg.setCancelable(false);
            dlg.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                                                    dlg1Showing = true;
                    dlg0Showing = false;

                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Info", "Doing task...", true);
                        }
                    });
            dlg.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Continue regardless",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            dlg0Showing = false;
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            dlg.show();
            return;
        }
    });
    //wait for dialogs to have completed
    while(dlg0Showing)
    {
        try{Thread.sleep(500);}
        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
    if(dlg1Showing)
    {
        doTask(args);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    //GC cleanup
    progressDialog = null;
}
```